# What's the Higher-Order Function Equivalent to this nested sapply()?

Tags: r, higher-order-functions

Surely there must be a better way to iterate the elements of vector `b` over the elements of vector `a`?

```
a <- 1:10
b  <- c("dog", "cat", "badger", "eagle", "horse")

sapply(1:length(a), function(x){
    sapply(1:length(b), function(y){
        cat(a[x], b[y], "\n\n")
    })
})
```

...gives ...

```
1 dog 

1 cat 

1 badger 

1 eagle 

1 horse 

2 dog 

2 cat 

2 badger 

2 eagle 

2 horse 

3 dog
```

...and so on. What is the Higher-Order Function Equivalent in R?
Thanks

Comment: `expand.grid(b, a)`

Answer (score 0):

This may not answer you question exactly but sometimes it is better to use `mapply` rather than nesting multiple `lapply`:

```
mapply(
  function(x, y) cat(x, y, "\n\n"),
  x = rep(a, times = length(b)),
  y = rep(b, each = length(a)))
```